# Active menu Changer on Sticky Bar

Tags: jquery, html

I have designed a Parallax Page with Sticky Menu bar. I need to change the active menu on scrolling. I have made it to change the active class on Click event. But I need it to do for the scroll event.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="main-menu">

    <ul>             
        <li><a class="active" href="#" data-delay="2000" data-appear="false" data-scrollto="#intro-slideshow">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-delay="2000" data-appear="false" data-scrollto="#overview">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-delay="2000" data-appear="false" data-scrollto="#categories">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-delay="2000" data-appear="false" data-scrollto="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Here is my JQuery Code for Onclick Active Menu Changer

```
$('*[data-scrollto]').click(function(){

        $( "a" ).removeClass( "active" );
        $(this).addClass("active");

        var dest = $(this).data('scrollto');                
        var pixels = $(dest).offset().top - 70;         
        var ms = Math.round(1000 + pixels/5);

        $('html, body').animate({               
            scrollTop: pixels
        }, ms, 'easeOutQuint');

    });
```

How do I change the active class on Scroll Event with the Data-Scrollto attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Without going into loads of detail. You need to bind the scroll event to the containing `element` or something like the window.

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Here's a demo of something very similar. I hope it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/vsmrnd7L/1/

EDIT:

```
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });

   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

Comment: Links only answers are highly depreciated. Please add some code with it. In case the link gets changed or destroyed, this becomes waste.

Comment: @Jay Moy : I have tried it on my web template. But the thing is that I couldn't link the section with in href="#" since the link is with Data-Scrollto attribute. I am weak with JQuery, so looking for your help in that section.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean? What have you tried?